# iOS : Call operator commands

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I was was wondering is there any possible way to call operators commands directly from application ? some codes like :

```
*149*124#
```

because I can't call this command

```
   UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if ([[device model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:*149*124# "]]];
    }
```

is there any API public or non-public for this issue ?

Comment: Do you mean call using the iPhone's phone app? You can use the `tel:` URL scheme for that.

Comment: Can you confirm that the 'if' succeeds?

Comment: I confirm that does not work ! see my edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:*149*124#"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:URL])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
}
```

Note that this will NOT work on the simulator, or an iPod / iPad, as they have no phone application.

Comment: @Mc.Lover What device are you trying to run this on?

Comment: i think those operator commands are not allowed for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

i just tested this:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://*149*124#"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:URL])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
}
```

and i saw this in the organizer console:

```
Mar  6 18:05:18 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Ignoring unsafe request to open URL tel://*149*124#
```

so this is blocked for security reasons, which makes sense to me

Comment: sorry. i don't care about private APIs. there is a reason why they are private.